# Android http post request fails when targeting new API version

Tags: android, post, android-networking

I've had no problems with my HTTP POST request until now.

```
try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 1000);
        client.setParams(params);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(NETWORK_CHECK_CONTROLLER_ADDRESS);
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);// here in 4.0
        String responseString = handler.handleResponse(response);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logReporter.add("Could not connect to controller");
        Log.d("4.0 tests",e.getCause()+" ");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

This request never failed or threw an exception when I was targeting API version 8. as specified in my manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Before it was

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Now my post request fails everytime and the exception message is always Null. What is different between android api 8 and 15 in terms of post requests?

Yes, I'm sure the server I'm POST'ing to is online. When I switch it back to api 8 all is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it be you're posting from the UI thread? In this case  an exception will be thrown starting from Gingerbread.

Comment: You can no longer do network posts from the main thread as of 3.0? At all?

Comment: @RyanGray do you think that is unreasonable or something? Doing so is dangerous as it can cause ANR dialogs and UI glitches/lags.

Comment: @Ryan Gray. That's correct starting from 3.0 it is not possible to do network operations from the main thread.

Comment: No it's not unreasonable for general purposes. But my app is for use only on a specific network where the POST requests are fast. Its a simple controller call to test connectivity to our private network. Takes less than a second. Anyway I've already done AsyncTask to fix this. I appreciate the reply

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are performing a network access on the main UI thread. Android 3.0 and above will crash your application (i.e. the system will throw a `NetworkAccessOnMainThread` exception) if you attempt to perform an HTTP request on the main thread. You need to wrap your HTTP request in an `AsyncTask` (or a `Thread` of some sorts) to ensure that you don't block the UI thread.

Read my blog post on the subject:

### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: Although you are, most probably, correct yet how did you figure out 'the problem IS in performing net ops from the UI thread'.

Comment: Because I've answered this problem a million times before on StackOverflow :). The error always occurs on this line: `HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);` and it only occured when the target sdk was 15 (instead of 8). So that's basically how I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 4.0+ version you have to call HTTP request in separate thread.